# Determine if menu item becomes an overflow, then show a mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a new type of responsive menu for my website that I believe would require some JavaScript. I am not very good with JavaScript so I am hoping someone can help me by giving directions, code samples or links to sites that can help provide solutions.

Basically, I have two navigation menu, their contents are the almost the same except that the first menu has all the links visible when viewed on a wide browser. The containing div for the first menu has overflow:hidden, such that when the browser is resized and is no longer wide enough to hold all the list items in one line, some of the list items will become hidden from view as they overflow. The first menu is also styled as a horizontal navigation bar.

The second menu, on the other hand is a dropdown menu, which will be triggered by clicking the More link. The list items on the second menu are set to `display:none`.

Here's what I want to happen. When a list item on the first menu becomes an overflow, and thus becomes hidden, I want the corresponding menu item on the second menu to become `display:block`. In other words, if

```
<li id="desktop_tenth">tenth</li>
```

goes hidden because it no longer fits the containing div, the

```
<li id="mobile_tenth">tenth</li>
```

becomes visible (when More link is clicked). I can do this using media queries on CSS3, but a JavaScript solution will be much preferred, so I hope someone can help me.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%;">
    <ul id="desktop">
        <li id="desktop_first">first</li>
        <li id="desktop_second">second</li>
        ...
        <li id="desktop_tenth">tenth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown_menu">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">More</a>
    <ul id="mobile">
        <li id="mobile_first">first</li>
        <li id="mobile_second">second</li>
        ...
        <li id="mobile_tenth">tenth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another approach to this would be to start with a

```
<div class="dropdown_menu">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">More</a>
    <ul id="mobile">
        <!--- no li inside this ul by default --->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Whatever li on the first menu get's hidden (or wrapped) will be appended to the

```
<ul id="mobile">

</ul>
```

as a list item.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `id`s for the menues' divs (e.g. `desktopMenu` and `mobileMenu`), like this:

```
<div id="desktopMenu" style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%;">
```

And this:

```
<div id="mobileMenu" class="dropdown_menu">
```

And use the following script:

```
var desktopMenu = document.getElementById('desktopMenu'), mobileMenu = document.getElementById('mobileMenu');

desktopMenu.style.display = 'none';
mobileMenu.style.display = 'none';

if (desktopMenu.offsetHeight < desktopMenu.scrollHeight || desktopMenu.offsetWidth < desktopMenu.scrollWidth) {
    mobileMenu.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    desktopMenu.style.display = 'block';
}
```

It hides both menues by default, and then determines if the `desktopMenu` div is overflowing. If it is, it shows the mobile menu, and if it's not, it shows the desktop menu. A solution using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would be much cleaner though.

Comment: Hi, @Campari. Thanks for the answer, but that does not actually help me achieve what I want. As you see, I don't really want to toggle between desktop and mobile menus. Instead, I want the list items (the links) to show on the second menu (#mobileMenu) when the corresponding link on the first menu (#desktopMenu) goes out of view as an effect of overflow:hidden of its container div.

Comment: The first thing I would want to do using jquery (if only I know how to do it) is to determine if a link (li) gets wrapped or gets hidden. Then, whatever li gets hidden, I will clone it and append it as a child of #mobileMenu ul.

Comment: @AaronJeffreyNolasco Sorry man, I responded in a hurry. This should give you an idea of how to do it: http://jsbin.com/asiyof/1. Note that I used jQuery and that I added `display: none` to the mobile menu so that it is shown only when you click on the Toggle link (which doesn't really toggle the menu, just shows it once). If you are not sure of how to add the jQuery library look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem using jQuery.

I get the overflowed menu items comparing the top position in the window with the top position of the first element in the menu.

```js
function getHiddenPosition() {
  var menuItems = $('ul#desktop > li');
  var length = menuItems.length;
  var position = 0;
  var top = $('ul#desktop > li').first().position().top;
  var nextLine = false;
  var currentTop;
  while ( !nextLine && position < length ) {
      currentTop = $(menuItems[position]).position().top;
      if ( currentTop > top ) {
       nextLine = true;
      } else {
       position++;
      }
  }
  return position;
}

function restartDropdown() {
  var length = $('ul#desktop > li').length;
  var position = getHiddenPosition();
  var mobileItems = $('ul#mobile > li');
  if ( position == length ) {
    $('.dropdown_menu').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.dropdown_menu').removeClass('hidden');
    $('ul#mobile > li').removeClass('hidden');
    for ( var i = 0; i < position; i++ ) {
      $(mobileItems[i]).addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
}

restartDropdown();

$(window).resize(restartDropdown);
```

```css
div.dropdown_menu.hidden, div.dropdown_menu li.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.inline_menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

ul#desktop li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline_menu">
    <ul id="desktop">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
        <li>Menu 6</li>
        <li>Menu 7</li>
        <li>Menu 8</li>
        <li>Menu 9</li>
        <li>Menu 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown_menu hidden">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">More</a>
    <ul id="mobile">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
        <li>Menu 6</li>
        <li>Menu 7</li>
        <li>Menu 8</li>
        <li>Menu 9</li>
        <li>Menu 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```